# Using ASP .NET MVC 2, Html.DropDownListFor - how to call a JQuery function on select?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using DropDownListFor in my view:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, 
                        new SelectList(ComponentsFactory.GetTypeList().Select(a => new { Name = Regex.Replace(a, @"^.*\.", ""), Value = a }).OrderBy(a => a.Name),
                            "Value", "Name", Model.Type), "Select . . .", null) %>
```

I also have a JQuery function in a .js scripts file that is already included in my header and everything:

```
function GetRequiredFields(type) 
{
...//do JQuery AJAX stuff
}
```

I want to call "GetRequiredFields" with parameter "type" as the value of the selected item on select, and use it to update a 'div' named "RequiredFields".  How can I do this?  Do I need to use something other than Html.DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, 
                    new SelectList(ComponentsFactory.GetTypeList().Select(a => new { Name = Regex.Replace(a, @"^.*\.", ""), Value = a }).OrderBy(a => a.Name),
                        "Value", "Name", Model.Type), "Select . . .", new { @onchange = "GetRequiredFields(this);" }) %>
```

The above `new { @onchange = "GetRequiredFields(this);" }` will create a new attribute `onchange` for the generated `<select>`.

and in your GetRequiredFields() add this

```
function GetRequiredFields(type) 
{
    var selectedValue = $(type).val();
    ...//do JQuery AJAX stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $('#Type').change(function(){GetRequiredFields( $(this).val() );});
});
```